Regex lookback multiple conditions
I have a string that could be as follows (1 possibility):
"1/1/2024; 02/01/2024; 2024-10-01" 

I want to return (from the right side) the last occurrence of multiple possible date formats:
mm/dd/yyyy, mm/dd/yy, yyyy-mm-dd, m/dd/yyyy, m/d/yyyy

So from the example above, find and return only 2024-10-01. How can I do this? I was thinking of using a lookback with OR condition, but it does not work:
(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{1}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d{2}/\d{1}/\d{4}|\d{1}/\d{1}/\d{4})


Which programming language (if any) do you use?

Hi, using python

Install the PyPi regex module (pip install regex) and run
import regex

text = "1/1/2024; 02/01/2024; 2024-10-01"
rx = r"\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b"
match = regex.search(rx, text, regex.REVERSE)
if match:
    print(match.group())

See the online demo
The regex.REVERSE flag searches for the match from the end of the string, so you get the last occurrence.
Note I added word boundaries on both sides of the pattern to make sure you only match the dates as whole words and shrank the pattern a bit. See the regex demo here.

...or, though not as clear, rx = r".*\K\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d\d?/\d\d?/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\b" then
match = regex.search(rx, text), as here

You don't need regex for this, just split the string on ; and convert the last value to a date object. If you already have pandas loaded, you can use to_datetime which will guess the format from your input string:
import pandas as pd

s = "1/1/2024; 02/01/2024; 2024-10-01"
out = pd.to_datetime(s.split(';')[-1]).date()

Output:
datetime.date(2024, 10, 1)

That can then be formatted however you like using strftime (e.g.):
out.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

Output:
'10/01/2024'


thx, using a reverse step is a good idea here!!

// Convert single digit `d-m` or  `m-d` to double digit format `dd-mm` or `mm-dd`

txt.replace(/(^|(?<=[;\s*\/\-]))\d{1}((?=[\/\-;\s])|$)/g, '0$&')

// split with ;  and then trim
.split(';').map(x => x.trim())

// finally matching regex format what you expect
.filter(x => (x.match(/^((\d{2}[\/\-]){2}\d{4})$/g) || x.match(/^(\d{4}([\/\-]\d{2}){2})$/g) ||  x.match(/^(\d{2}[\/\-]){2}\d{2}$/g))) 

Full code is here:


let txt = "1/1/2024; 2/1/2024; 2024-10-1; 3/3/2024; 2005-3-3; 24-06-06";

let res = txt.replace(/(^|(?<=[;\s*\/\-]))\d{1}((?=[\/\-;\s])|$)/g, '0$&').split(';').map(x => x.trim())
.filter(x => (x.match(/^((\d{2}[\/\-]){2}\d{4})$/g) || x.match(/^(\d{4}([\/\-]\d{2}){2})$/g) ||  x.match(/^(\d{2}[\/\-]){2}\d{2}$/g))) ;

console.log(res);




This my result contains format: 
mm/dd/yyyy, mm/dd/yy, yyyy-mm-dd, m/dd/yyyy, m/d/yyyy
year, month, day separator are | or -
Thank You

If the date at the end has a space in front of it (or a comma or semicolon) then you can capture the last date like this:
.+[; ,](.+)$


You can view this example online here including explanations of each piece.

The grouping done by parentheses is better explained here.



Hello, I am using Python

Thx. where do I add the list of date values to this: .+;(.+)$      Here's the list of values: \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{1}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d{2}/\d{1}/\d{4}|\d{1}/\d{1}/\d{4}

You don't put the values into the regex, you just have it in a variable and then call the regex function needed. You can store the result in a variable as well, like this:
pattern = '.+;(.+)$'
test_string = '1/1/2024; 02/01/2024; 2024-10-01'
result = re.match(pattern, test_string)

Unfortunately the dates are not always separated by a semi colon (that was just 1 example, sometimes it's seperated by a space, comma, etc). It's a free form field. here are 4 examples (below). I need to find the far right most date (could be 1, could be more than 1) in different formats:
EXAMPLE 1=12/06/2023
EXAMPLE 2 = 1/21/2023, 4:00 am – 1:56am – 11/24/2023
EXAMPLE 3 = 2:54pm – 2:00pm – 2023-1-30; 9:49am – 11:56am – 2023-11-28
EXAMPLE 4 = 11/6/23 from 1018 to 1245, 12/15/23

I've slightly modified the answer above to check for commas and spaces as well, since it looks like spaces might be the most likely to catch what you need. However, because it is freeform text field you can never have a fool-proof solution. Someone can always enter half a date or enter a date with too many numbers, etc. There is no way to guarantee you get the right thing because the right thing might not exist.

If you want to add more possible values that could appear in front of your final value, just put them in the list after the comma. For example [; ,–]
